# Is it possible to replicate the "magic" of OptionPatterns[] with DynamicModule's local variables?

Tags: programming, dynamic

Creating richer interactive interfaces that are generated by a `DynamicModule` invariably requires more complex data structures and in particular, a larger argument space as specified by `DynamicModule`'s local variables. Managing the extra functionality within `DynamicModule`'s body then inevitably involves the need for ongoing code modularization which in turn requires repeated passing down of this argument space.

Here's an example for a 2-element argument space.

```
SetAttributes[Component1,HoldAll];
SetAttributes[Component2,HoldAll];
SetAttributes[Component3,HoldAll];
Component1[x_,y_]:=Button["Increase x",x++];
Component2[x_,y_]:=Button["Decrease y",y--];
Component3[x_,y_]:={Dynamic@x,Dynamic@y};

DynamicModule[{x=1,y=2},
Row[{Component1[x,y],Component2[x,y],Component3[x,y]}]]
```

This is not a problem for only 2 arguments but becomes a serious issue for larger argument spaces both for reading and writing code. For writing not only does the whole argument space need to be re-typed each time a new piece of modularization or functionality is added, but any changes to this argument space (as part of ongoing design changes for example) then requires changes throughout the code base. The reading issue revolves around a function's arguments clogging valuable space while distracting from the function's logic.

Ideally what is needed is to replicate the "magic" of `OptionsPattern[]` but for local `DynamicModule` variables in which these variables can be modified in a single place and have the effects automatically cascade (a bonus would be for the syntax colouring to be maintained in the body of any function accessing variables in this space).

Roughly - with `obj` denoting the variable space - something like:

```
(* not correct syntax *)

Component1[obj] := Button["Increase x", x++];
Component2[obj] := Button["Decrease y", y--];
Component3[obj] := {Dynamic@x, Dynamic@y};

obj = {x = 1, y = 2};

DynamicModule[obj,
Column[{Component1[obj], Component2[obj], Component3[obj]}]]
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass every variable to all functions? This seems quite at odds with the idea of having a function in the first place.

Comment: You might find the following toolkit helpful if you are interested in doing serious GUI development from within Mathematica:  [Bailey's Super Widget Package](http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/superwidgetpackage/userguide.pdf)

Comment: I think I've invested too much in the UI within Mma although I wonder if David will one day introduce functionality to automatically translate Mma UIs into Java equivalents? - probably asking a bit much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a case for using (delayed) rules. In particular, I suggest the following:

```
ClearAll[Component1, Component2, Component3];
Component1[obj_] := Button["Increase x", Increment["x"]] /. obj;
Component2[obj_] := Button["Decrease y", Decrement["y"]] /. obj;
Component3[obj_] := Unevaluated[{Dynamic["x"], Dynamic["y"]}] /. obj;
```

where `obj` is supposed to be a rule or, generally, list of rules. Then:

```
DynamicModule[{obj, x = 1, y = 2},
    obj = {"x" :> x, "y" :> y}; 
    Column[{Component1[obj], Component2[obj], Component3[obj]}]]
```

will do what you want. Since rules are flexible, you can add more elements without affecting the existing code. Rules are used as a device of concise injection of unevaluated code, state in this case.

In some sense, what is happening here is non-trivial, since all components are actually functioning like tiny macros, with the full code being "assembled" at run-time. I generally think that the best way to construct complex UI-s in Mathematica is through code-generation.

Comment: "I generally think that the best way to construct complex UI-s in Mathematica is through code-generation." Are their use-cases you can envisage for which this code-generation idiom has advantages over jVincent's answer?

Comment: @RonaldMonson Yes, there are. Have a look e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551647/how-to-define-part-of-a-manipulate-control-variable-definition-to-reduce-code-du) to see what code generation can buy you. Basically, there are "theoretical" advantages of it: any comples UI in mma is a (large) Mathematica expression with often complex embedded state, and usually not easily amenable to breaking into smaller chunks. I know a bunch of cases where code generation allows to dramatically simplify life.

Comment: @RonaldMonson With more complex / larger UI, a lack of proper encapsulation (global variables used in many places without control) can make life miserable. Code generation may allow one to combine widgets from smaller ones, and test those in isolation. Using usual functions is often not an option since lots of expressions are held, and one then need complicated code injection mechanisms.

Comment: I see the similarity in the code-generation idiom with the linked example but that seems to be solving a different problem associated more with code-refactoring whereas this seems to be more of a scoping issue.

The advantage of this code-generation idiom to "dramatically simplify life" I agree with and use it quite a bit myself (but not in the exact way you showed). Having said this, sometimes beyond a certain threshold there can be a trap to move more and more logic into this generic code-generation template as it increasingly strains to accommodate different situations.

Comment: ... Sometimes I find it easier to just do a copy and paste of a basic template and modify this with the specific logic. I guess it depends on how common the "common factor" is. Anyway, what is aimed for in this post is to address the  "not easily amenable to breaking into smaller chunks." of complex UI. This idiom does allow the variable definitions to be done in the one place as requested but I don't quite see any advantages over the "no argument" solution since effectively the same code ends up getting generated but with more involved syntax.

Comment: @RonaldMonson The advantage is that all the component functions do not carry any state, and therefore can be tested in isolation, since they don't depend on the environment. This is a toy example, which is why this advantage does not look like a big deal. For comples UI-s,  this testability of components and isolation of state makes a big difference. The whole point of code-generation  is that you can test relevant parts separately, and only very rarely have to resort to the full generated expression for testing. This is similar to compilation.

Comment: I see your point but in complex UIs defined by an overarching DynamicModule it is usually the case that variables are dynamically connected in complex ways and hence testing invariably involves *all* the components. In other words components communicate so that instead of "resorting" to the full generated expression for testing shouldn't this be something that is done as a matter of course?

Comment: @RonaldMonson The usual way I test functional code is that I  take a function call out of its enclosing function of which it is a part, and test it on some data separately. The same is true for the UI in this approach: you take out a given component, and test it with a simpler environment (state). You still need to create some state for the tests, but it can be much simpler than in the real case that gives you trouble. A more standard approach to UI (used in say Java or Javascript) is based on event-handling model where events are explicit objects, and one writes event handlers. This has ...

Comment: @RonaldMonson ...its problems (complexity, lots of mutable state), but at least allows you to test the propagation of a given event separately. In Mathematica, the event handling is done for you by the mechanism of symbol tracking in Dynamic. This makes coding easier but debugging harder, because you have no direct access to individual events causing this or that. Code generation allows one to alleviate this situation by having automatic means of generating simpler UIs for all components involved, and allows one to use the "functional" style of debugging for UIs.

Comment: The way I design UI is component by component so this is where my "chunking" takes place but this seems qualitatively different from chunking I'm used to in the functional programming of traditional packages. In functional programming you go after the smallest, useful functional unit and then chain these together DAG-like. For debugging here then, divide & conquer seems appropriate. In UI however, the automatic symbolic tracking means divide and conquer (i.e. by variable) doesn't seem to work so well since it is difficult to predict where to divide (and sometimes what to conquer!).

Comment: Component1, Component2, Component3 might ostensibly be assocated with Variable set X, Y, Z, according to their displayed values in the UI but actually be dependent on almost any subset of the entire set of variables as the components interact.

It doesn't seem natural to try to track these interactions in a single piece of code (or  in my experience particularly fruitful) since this is what the symbolic tracker is designed for. In fact I am continually impressed at how intuitively Mathematica allows these interactions to be implemented and ...

Comment: beyond a certain point I spend most of my debugging in managing arguments rather than chasing the symbolic tracker.

It almost seems like a more "holistic" (and I hate to get new-agey here) debugging/testing approach is called for in this type of UI. In fact by doing so holistically (i.e. using the full UI Expression) the presence of the other components allows quicker testing over wider ranges. This of course has implications for testing and validation suites and this may be an indicator of the limitations of the functional approach in this UI context - can traditional unit testiing match

Comment: a more holistic approach for these UI?

Of course, it may be that I am trying to "conquer" the wrong thing in a UI I am considering. I am trying to pack in a lot of "functionality" as I think that it is with this scope comes a certain usefulness.

At any rate, thanks v.much for your input and advice, I may end up developing this in parallel using 2-3 of these methods and see which one is easiest as I'm not convinced your method is not the best :)

Comment: @RonaldMonson But the approach to UI debugging you describe is exactly the one which is made possible with code generation. Basically, you don't divide and conquere a complicated state, instead you automatically generate smaller systems and consider those in their entirety. This is what code generation buys you - basically, your specific UI becomes just one of the possible family of UI-s which you can generate with the same components more or less automatically. So, it gives you a continuous simplification path. Also, when you develop in this way, it becomes more clear how to divide the ...

Comment: @RonaldMonson ...total state into loosely coupled parts, which then encapsulate those parts of the state and isolate from others. Thanks for the accept b.t.w., I will try digging some larger and more convincing example and add it to my answer as time permits.

Comment: Ok, code generation gives you arbitrary system granularity where granularity is components + variables. Using the globalized approach gives you arbitrary granularity in components but not in variables (forced to take them all) and therefore no arbitrary system granularity.

Answer (score 3):

Declaring the components inside the `DynamicModule` would allow you to have access to all Dynamic Module variables.

```
DynamicModule[{Component1, Component2, Component3, x = 1, y = 2},
   Component1[] := Button["Increase x", x++];
   Component2[] := Button["Decrease y", y--];
   Component3[] := {Dynamic@x, Dynamic@y};
 Row[{Component1[], Component2[], Component3[]}]]
```

Usually using global (or in this case semi-global) variables is frowned upon, but here it might do the trick.

As an added bonus, the syntax colouring of variables in the functions is correct.

Comment: Similar to jVincent's answer except with the use of "[]" makes the `SetAttributes` calls redundant (is it really a function to justify their inclusion?). As written the syntax colouring will be preserved but usually the components are more complex and need to be defined in other notebook cells so this colouring won't be preserved in general.

Comment: @RonaldMonson Yes, his answer is indeed similar to mine:) You're right about the `SetAttribues`, I was in a hurry.

Comment: +1 Indeed, going by own absorbed chronology :) And yes the form of the generality wasn't mentioned in the question so can't complain about it not appearing in an answer. I think the principle behind the colouring is an interesting feature that can/will be extended in many different directions which I will mention when I get some time and so want to avoid losing it if possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you want each component to have access to the entire scope, rather then pass it through as an argument to a function, you can also just not have any function at all:

```
 Component1 := Button["Increase x", x++];
 Component2 := Button["Decrease y", y--];
 Component3 := {Dynamic@x, Dynamic@y};

 DynamicModule[{x = 1, y = 2},
 Row[{Component1, Component2, Component3}]
 ]
```

Comment: This seems to be the "obvious" (obviously not to myself!) solution and goes to your comment about the need to have a function at all. I guess the bundle of a function's advantages -collecting up repeatable transformation into a single callable unit, only changing what is necessary and the clarity gained from modularization-instilled an imperative to always want to provide arguments. When only the last advantage is needed this imperative disappears. I think in the back of my mind is also Ajasja's comment "Usually using global (or in this case semi-global) variables is frowned upon" ...

Comment: … I assume he is alluding to such a practice causing unexpected changes in the state with code chunks telling you what is to be modified- both of which perhaps are not so much an issue in this context?
(bearing in mind that deeper transformations likely to be repeatable can always be lazily functionalized and used with these semi-global variables)