# Selectively updating individual graphics in a dynamic, multiple-plot Show

Tags: dynamic, graphics

Suppose `Show` contains multiple graphics objects that differ markedly in the amount of computation needed for their display. Hence, when dynamically updating only those individual graphics changed by any underlying variable change should be redrawn. For example (and with apologies to Dutch patriots), in the following dynamic `Show`, "pulling the red down" (by dragging the l.h.s locator) should take longer than "pulling the blue up" (by dragging the r.h.s. locator) since it is a more computationally intensive graphic (as simulated here by `Pause@0.1`). Dragging the r.h.s. locator however, is equally sluggish due to the overarching `Dynamic` wrapper causing both graphics to update whenever either locator is dragged. The logical solution would seem to be to wrap each inner `Plot` graphic in a `Dynamic` but `Show` doesn't like this apparently expecting a pure graphic for each of its shown components.

```
DynamicModule[{top = {.02, 0.15}, bottom = {.08, 0.08}},
 Dynamic@
  Show[
   Plot[(Pause@.01; top[[2]]), {x, 0, .1}, Filling -> Top,FillingStyle -> Red],
   Plot[bottom[[2]], {x, 0, .1}, Filling -> Axis,FillingStyle -> Blue],
   Graphics@Locator[Dynamic[top, (top[[2]] = #[[2]]) &]],
   Graphics@Locator[Dynamic[bottom, (bottom[[2]] = #[[2]]) &]],
  PlotRange -> {0, .2}, Axes -> False]]
```

[image]

`Overlay`, on the other hand, has no such qualms as indicated by the following graphic being much more responsive to the r.h.s. `VerticalSlider` "pulling the blue up".

```
DynamicModule[{top = {.02, 0.15},bottom = {.08, 0.08}},
 {VerticalSlider[Dynamic[top[[2]]], {0, 0.15}],
  Overlay[{
   Dynamic@Plot[(Pause@.01; top[[2]]), {x, 0, .1}, Filling -> Top,FillingStyle -> Red, Axes -> False,PlotRange -> {0, .2}],
   Dynamic@Plot[bottom[[2]], {x, 0, .1}, Filling -> Axis,FillingStyle -> Blue, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {0, .2}]}], 
  VerticalSlider[Dynamic[bottom[[2]]], {0, 0.15}]}]
```

[image]

This is not a permanent solution as `Overlay` doesn't enjoy `Show`'s more natural way of combining plots (more intuitive formatting, locator usage, ability to set common graphics options etc) so the question is; how can `Overlay`'s selective updating be replicated in `Show`?

**Answer Update:**

The following answer is a hybrid taking from both Jens and Mr Wizard's responses which I think help to nicely illustrate some more general points about dynamic interface design. First, the combined answer:

```
SetAttributes[{DynamicShow, DynamicPlotRed, DynamicPlotBlue}, HoldAll];

DynamicShow[p_Plot] := Graphics[Dynamic@p[[1]], p[[2]]];

DynamicPlotRed[top_] := DynamicShow@Plot[(Pause@.01; top[[2]]), {x, 0, .1}, Filling -> Top, FillingStyle -> Red]

DynamicPlotBlue[bottom_] := DynamicShow@Plot[bottom[[2]], {x, 0, .1}, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Blue]

DynamicModule[{top = {.02, 0.15},bottom = {.08, 0.08}},
 Show[
  DynamicPlotRed@top,
  DynamicPlotBlue@bottom,
  Graphics@Locator[Dynamic[top, (top[[2]] = #[[2]]) &]],
  Graphics@Locator[Dynamic[bottom, (bottom[[2]] = #[[2]]) &]],
 PlotRange -> {0, .2}, Axes -> False]]
```

[image]

This includes the desired, lower level (indirect) use of `Dynamic` to maintain the usefulness of its automatic, targeting updating as captured in Mr Wizard's answer. This is important as it allows a more general, more numerous adding of interface components (note the relevant `Dynamic` sits in `DynamicShow` to which I'll return). The approach in Jens' answer - having each `Locator` directly update the corresponding plot, while working perfectly for the quoted two-element example, doesn't generalize in the sense that all plot updating now needs to be done "by hand" or via `Dynamic`'s second argument *without* harnessing `Dynamic`'s automatic updating (in full generality "Plot" can be an arbitrarily complex interface component with multiple, not-immediately-obvious dependencies).

There is a potential issue in that this solution relies on a consistent `FullForm` being generated by `Plot` but this can be addressed by adding a helper function. For example, using the `PlotLegend` option changes the `FullForm` structure but this can be handled as follows:

```
SetAttributes[{DynamicShow, DynamicShowLegend, DynamicPlotRed, DynamicPlotBlue}, HoldAll];

DynamicShow[p_Plot] := Graphics[Dynamic@p[[1]], p[[2]]];

DynamicShowLegend[p_] /; (! FreeQ[Hold@p, PlotLegends]) := Legended[Graphics[Dynamic@p[[1, 1]]], p[[2]]];

DynamicPlotRed[top_] := DynamicShow@Plot[(Pause@.01; top[[2]]), {x, 0, .1}, Filling -> Top, FillingStyle -> Red]

DynamicPlotBlue[bottom_] := DynamicShowLegend@Plot[{x, bottom[[2]]}, {x, 0, .1}, Filling -> {1 ->{Axis, Green}, 2 -> {Axis, Blue}}, PlotLegends -> True]


DynamicModule[{top = {.02, 0.15}, bottom = {.08, 0.08}},
 Show[
  DynamicPlotRed@top,
  DynamicPlotBlue@bottom,
  Graphics@Locator[Dynamic[top, (top[[2]] = #[[2]]) &]],
  Graphics@Locator[Dynamic[bottom, (bottom[[2]] = #[[2]]) &]],
  PlotRange -> {0, .2}, Axes -> False]]
```

[image]

The functions introduced in Jens' answer also illustrate a fundamental principle for building more complex dynamic interfaces. While introduced here to make `Dynamic`'s second argument more readable, this improved readability assumes much greater proportions as interfaces' complexify (essentially implementing modularization with all its attended advantages, as, for example, enumerated in Tom Wickham-Jones [white paper](http://www.wolfram.com/products/workbench/)). There is a wrinkle in performing such modularization when it comes to dynamic interfaces however, which can be illustrated by seeing how Mr Wizard's solution modularizes (in fact generalizes).

Essentially his insight was that `Show` apparently (mostly) expects `Graphics` heads in its arguments (with exceptions noted as above) so that wrapping one of these in a `Dynamic` upsets this obstinance (which I regard as a design oversight). This can now however, at least be accommodated by giving `Show` its cherished `Graphics` head and instead wrapping `Dynamic` around `Graphic`'s first argument via `Graphics[Plot[...][[1]], AspectRatio->1/GoldenRatio]`. The `AspectRatio` option corresponds to that generated automatically in this plot but in fact any generated option value can be included by defining

```
DynamicShow[p_Plot]:=Graphics[Dynamic@p[[1]],p[[2]]]
```

(n.b. The `FullForm` of a `Plot` output is `Graphics[comps, opts]` )

The wrinkle is that in order to apply `DynamicShow` in this way, its argument, `p`, needs to avoid evaluation prior to being wrapped in `Dynamic` to maintain its own  "lexical scoping" (a form of code generation/injection). Consequently, this dynamic variable needs to be held right through to its final placement nestled inside a `Dynamic` thereby requiring a chain of `HoldAll` attributions.

In a fuller generality, the passed-through variable need not just be a local `DynamicModule` variable holding a pair of numbers like `top` and `bottom` but instead can potentially hold an arbitrary large dataset. This suggests an updated, less-emulative, idiom for answering an earlier  [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10627/is-it-possible-to-replicate-the-magic-of-optionpatterns-with-dynamicmodules) about realizing such modularization in dynamic interfaces; that is, there appears to now be a sufficient level of mutability in the new associations/datasets for expressions like `top[[2]]` to be fruitfully extended to expressions like `interfaceData[[ ...]]`.

Comment: Your code generates errors because of how you use `Dynamic` inside `Locator`, just so you know. ("Cannot assign to raw object 0.08`" etc.)

Comment: @Pickett - no errors are generated on my set-up "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)" - Dynamic can be used like this inside a Locator can it not?

Comment: There were indeed errors as @Pickett observed, due to the argument of the `Locator` containing a constant and not a variable. I posted a version that fixes this and also addresses the `Show` issue.

Comment: As my preferred answer is a composite from both Mr Wizard's and Jens' responses, I'm unable to decide which one to accept. Jens' answer modularized the plotting, reminded about always having `Dynamic`'s second argument up one's sleeve and answered the question as posed.  Mr Wizard's answer, on the other hand, captured the preservation of `Dynamic`'s automatic tracking though lower-level placement of dynamic the actual sought-after idiom whose hinting lay in the accompanying `Overlay` example. On the other, other hand, Jen's modularization provided the opportunity to put this in a broader ...

Comment: context of interface design. As usual when faced with such indecision, I inject randomness -  here tinged with some "real-time, democracy"; if the number of question votes (currently 2) is odd/even at GMT midday 28th August Jens/MrWizard gets the nod.

Comment: My advice is that if you can get by without taking apart the output of built-in functions such as `Plot`, then that's less likely to break in future versions. The introduction of `PlotLegends` illustrates this. It creates `Plot` output with `Head` `Legended` instead of `Graphics`. In earlier versions, that didn't happen, so that code relying on the internal structure of `Plot` output from the old version will not work. My solution doesn't rely on any undocumented internal structures.

Comment: @Jens your point about some `Plot's` `FullForm` not having `Graphics` as a `Head` is well-made (and in the answer I've factored this in with an extended definition - thanks!) however as per the updated answer it is important here that `Dynamic` be used at the inner level for the dependencies reasons outlined (it also makes the code more readable). Hence the extra advantage these inner `Dynamic`s offer IMO outweighs any potential compatibility issues. If there are any future variations in `Plot`'s `FullForm` then these can always be incorporated as needed ...

Comment: (even better, maybe future versions will automate this process with a design extension). I also agree that compatibility issues need to be increasingly factored due to the exponentially increasing functionality released with each new version. What this points to though I think, is the imperative for more routine use of (higher level) version control and unit testing so that, for example, if `Plot` does subsequently change and break a given codebase, it can quickly be picked up and rectified.

Comment: @Pickett yes my typo was to use `Dynamic[{.02, top[[2]]}]` instead of `Dynamic[top, (top[[2]] = #[[2]]) &]` now corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the difficulties in your first approach is that you're trying to use `Plot` to dynamically generate rectangles. It would be easier to use graphics primitives for that. However, I'll assume that you have a reason to use `Plot`, so let's simulate the two plotting functions more clearly (one of them with a `Pause` to indicate its delay). I define two plotting functions (`plotRed` and `plotBlue`) here, depending on the parameter `param` which is controlled by the locators.

In the `Locator`, I use the variables `p1` and `p2` as the 2D positions, and then use the *second* argument to `Locator` to invoke a function that processes these positions. First, we want to constrain `p1` and `p2` to move only vertically. This is done by setting the horizontal coordinate to the fixed value determined by `top` and `bottom`.

The whole `Show` expression is now wrapped in `Dynamic`, but the updating of the two plots, called `plot1` and `plot2`, is done directly in the second `Locator` argument, as part of the function that is executed whenever the locator changes.

```
plotRed[param_] := 
 Plot[Pause[.01]; param, {x, 0, .1}, Filling -> Top, 
  FillingStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {{0, .2}, {0, .2}}]

plotBlue[param_] := 
 Plot[param, {x, 0, .1}, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, .2}, {0, .2}}]

DynamicModule[
 {p1, p2,
  plot1, plot2, top = {.02, 0.15}, bottom = {.08, 0.08}},
 p1 = top;
 p2 = bottom;
 plot1 = plotRed[p1[[2]]];
 plot2 = plotBlue[p2[[2]]];
 Deploy@Dynamic@Show[
    plot1, plot2,
    Graphics@Locator[
      Dynamic[
       p1, (p1 = {top[[1]], #[[2]]}; 
         plot1 = (plotRed[#[[2]]])) &]],
    Graphics@Locator[
      Dynamic[
       p2, (p2 = {bottom[[1]], #[[2]]}; 
         plot2 = plotBlue[#[[2]]]) &]],
    Axes -> False,
    PlotRange -> {{0, .2}, {0, .2}}]]
```

As an additional modification, I added a fixed `PlotRange` to all plots (including the vertical extent).

The resulting display now shows the longer delay only when moving the locator for the slow plotting function, as you were asking.

Answer (score 2):

I apologize for the quality of this answer: unlike Jens I did not bother to correct errors.

I would like to illustrate that even when the first argument of `Graphics` is invalid the layout engine can still render the size and aspect ratio the expression of these are given:

```
Graphics["foo", ImageSize -> {50, 200}]
Graphics["bar", ImageSize -> {200, 50}]
```

[image]

Because of this you can place `Dynamic` *inside* of `Graphics` and `Show` will still combine your expressions:

```
DynamicModule[{top = {.02, 0.15}, bottom = {.08, 0.08}},
 Show[
  Graphics[Dynamic@
    Plot[(Pause@.01; top[[2]]), {x, 0, .1}, Filling -> Top, FillingStyle -> Red][[1]], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, .1}, {0, .2}}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio],

  Graphics[Dynamic@
    Plot[bottom[[2]], {x, 0, .1}, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Blue][[1]], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, .1}, {0, .2}}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio],

  Graphics@Locator[Dynamic[{.02, top[[2]]}]],
  Graphics@Locator[Dynamic[{.08, bottom[[2]]}]],

  PlotRange -> {0, .2},
  Axes -> False
 ]
]
```

[image]

Notes:

- I use `Part` to extract the graphics primitives from `Plot` output
- I needed to set the `PlotRange` and `AspectRatio` in `Graphics` for them to be displayed correctly

Comment: This won't work if you add `PlotLegends` to one or both of the plots (e.g.).

Comment: @Jens see the combined answer above to address this

Comment: @RonaldMonson In your updated post, the statement that `Show` expects `Graphics` is not correct. Besides `Graphics3D`, it also accepts `Legended@Graphics` and `Legended@Graphics3D`. My point is the `Plot` can produce the `Legended` output, too, and I automatically account for that.

Comment: @Jens I'd argue that `Show` "expects" `Graphics` but not exclusively so :)  but yes, you are right, I'd overlooked `Legended` etc and the answer is now adjusted. Thanks.